# How to obtain a reference to a dynamically generated (unknown named) child element in json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json in the format:

```
"json": {
    "schema": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "My Table",
      "properties": {
        "table-1659555454697": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "inputTest": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "columnTwo": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "inputTest",
              "columnTwo"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
    },
```

I can obtain a reference to the "table-1659555454697" object with:

```
console.log(this.jsf.schema.properties);
```

What I'm struggling with is how to obtain a reference from that element's children to the "required" array's length. Assuming I cannot reference "table-1659555454697" by name since its dynamically generated.

I've tried:

```
 console.log(this.jsf.schema.properties[0].items[0].required.length);
```

But I get undefined error

Comment: `properties` is an object, not an array so you can't access it by index. You would need to access the Object.values if you don't know the property name. `Object.values(this.jsf.schema.properties)[0].required.length`

Comment: You have the object; you access its properties like any other object.  Are you instead asking how to iterate over the keys and/or values of the “properties” object?

Comment: I need to determine if the object represented by "table-1659555454697" contains a "required" array

Comment: @DaveNewton, essentially yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), or [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). They provide an array of, respectively, the object's keys, the object's values, and the object's key-value pairs (as an array of `[key, value]` arrays).

```js
const propertyNames = Object.keys(json.schema.properties) // ["table-1659555454697"]
const propertyValues = Object.values(json.schema.properties) // [{ type: "array", items: { ... }]
const propertyEntries = Object.entries(json.schema.properties)
// [ ["table-1659555454697", [{ type: "array", items: { ... }] ]
```

So we could do what you want like this:

```js
const requiredLength = Object.values(json.schema.properties)[0].items.required.length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference *table-1659555454697* by doing

```js
Object.keys(this.jsf.schema.properties)[0]
```